# Sum of $n$ positive real numbers is 1. Estimate subsums of k elements.

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, problem-solving, pigeonhole-principle

Sum of $n$ positive real numbers $a_1, ...,a_n$ is $1$. Let $S_k$ be maximal sum of k distinct elements of $a_n$. (they can be equal but must have different indexes). What is $\sup S_k$ and $\inf S_k$ among all sequences of length $n$? For $k=1$ or $k=n-1$we can use Pigeonhole Principle. How to handle other cases? What if numbers are nonnegative?

Please provide a hint unless solution is non-trivial. Thanks!

Comment: I think it should be 1 as $\ S_{k} $  can attain any value below 1. And we can construct such an n-element sequence.

Comment: Something to start with: you can assume $a_1\leq a_2\leq...\leq a_n$.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

Say you get the choose the largest $k$ numbers out of $n$ numbers.( think amounts of money). The total amount is $\$1000$. What is the worst case scenario for you?  If it makes is easier, take $n=10$, and $k=3$.